# Yii2 Basic App HtAccess Rules when deploying on shared server

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have set up a site with the yii2 basic app, everything works fine on my localhost, I just deployed my application by cloning the repo from git on the root of `/public_html` folder updated composer and ran the migrations, all went fine after that I added

`public_html/.htaccess`

and

`public_html/web/.htaccess`

files with the following set of rules

**public_html/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

**public_html/web/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

**UrlManager in `config/web.php`**

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'baseUrl' => sprintf(
            "%s://%s", isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
    ),
    'rules' => [
        '' => 'site/index',
        'tos' => 'site/tos',
        'privacy-policy' => 'site/privacy',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
    ],
],
```

Whatever i do i always land on the home page i have 3 links in the footer Terms&conditions Contact and Privacy Policy, they all are showing the home page although the url shown in the address bar is correctly transalated by the `UrlManager` to be right but the view loaded is always home page you.

Note : i havent cloned the repo outside the public_html folder as the Yii2 guide says, instead i have cloned the git repo inside the `public_html`, i dont think it is not doable, as the advanced app works too if cloned inside the `publich_html` rather than outside

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] use this instead of RewriteRule . index.php.

Comment: you are talking about the rule declared in `public_html/web/.htaccess` ? it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [symlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) for this. You can put project anywhere and only create symlinks to directories forced by your hosting. For example, put project in `~/domains/example.com/project` and create symlink to `public_html` directory.

```
cd ~/domains/example.com
# remove old public_html directory
mv public_html old_public_html
# create symlink for webroot
ln -s ./project/web public_html
```

No need to change your project structure and no twisted rewrite rules.

Comment: hey i never saw this answer, yes this could work out as intended i didnt tried it but its logical, i am accepting it as an answer as i was intending not to clone the repo outside `public_html` as it becomes too messy with the files structure, but will provide feedback when i will try this approach, thanks alot for answering.

Comment: Hello Rob, a quick question will this work correctly with `'enablePrettyUrl' => true,` ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yeah, never had any problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

Yii 2 Basic app has to placed outside the `public_html` directory as described in the docs and you cant setup inside the `public_html` and instead you have to rename the `web` to `public_html` and then clone it outside the `public_html` directory so that it is overridden by your renamed folder `(web -> public_html)` contents.